# How to encrypt a string in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I have to encrypt/decrypt some sensitive information in a Xml file?
Yes I can do that by writing my own custom algorithms. I am wondering if there is already a built in way in .NET to do that and also what points I always need to take care..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a couple of functions that use the .NET framework to encrypt and decrypt a string:

```
public string EncryptString(string plainText)
{
    // Instantiate a new RijndaelManaged object to perform string symmetric encryption
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();

    // Set key and IV
    rijndaelCipher.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("ABC");
    rijndaelCipher.IV = Convert.FromBase64String("123");

    // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    // Instantiate a new encryptor from our RijndaelManaged object
    ICryptoTransform rijndaelEncryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();

    // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
    // memory stream
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndaelEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Convert the plainText string into a byte array
    byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);

    // Encrypt the input plaintext string
    cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

    // Complete the encryption process
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // Convert the encrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
    byte[] cipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();

    // Convert the encrypted byte array to a base64 encoded string
    string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

    // Return the encrypted data as a string
    return cipherText;
}


public string DecryptString(string cipherText)
{
    // Instantiate a new RijndaelManaged object to perform string symmetric encryption
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();

    // Set key and IV
    rijndaelCipher.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("ABC");
    rijndaelCipher.IV = Convert.FromBase64String("123");

    // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    // Instantiate a new encryptor from our RijndaelManaged object
    ICryptoTransform rijndaelDecryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor();

    // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
    // memory stream
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndaelDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Will contain decrypted plaintext
    string plainText = String.Empty;

    try
    {
        // Convert the ciphertext string into a byte array
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        // Decrypt the input ciphertext string
        cryptoStream.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

        // Complete the decryption process
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Convert the decrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
        byte[] plainBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        // Convert the encrypted byte array to a base64 encoded string
        plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
    }

    // Return the encrypted data as a string
    return plainText;
}
```

Of course I don't advise hardcoding the key and initialisation vector like this :)

Comment: "ABC" & "123" are invalid lengths for a Base-64 char array.

Comment: It was only meant to be an illustration, but fair point ;)

Comment: Just to add value for the other visitors here - the length of both key and IV can be 24 characters. For example: "keJhDo9YvJsp01j4JUdVuE=="

Comment: Just a sidenote: Use Encoding.UTF8 instead of Encoding.ASCII, because the world is NOT an english-only place.

Comment: @Quandary It was only meant to be an illustration, but fair point ;)

Comment: IV must be different for each encryption.

Comment: @DavidThibault the fixed IV was only meant as an illustration, but yes, it should be different each time you encrypt. You should normally use `rijndaelCipher.GenerateIV()` to generate a unique IV

Answer (score 10):

You will probably want to dive into the [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace. I guess the articles [Cryptography Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92f9ye3s.aspx), [Encrypting Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af.aspx) and [Decrypting Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te15te69.aspx) at MSDN could be good starters.